# WPF chart with x-axis selection

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts

I've been searching around for a chart with interactive selection. The idea is you have a long narrow chart with a rectangle overlay which had a handle at each end, this overlay is effectively a selection of some data on the chart. You can expand the overlay to increase selection, also you can drag the overlay accross the charts x axis to move to a point in time.

There is a silverlight [demo from Component one](http://demo.componentone.com/silverlight/StockPortfolio/) with the functionality I'm after (you have to click the chart icon for a stock in the grid to see the functionality I'm after). If possible something open source.

Here is [another similar demo](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/visitors.html) of the functionality here (but not complete functionality).

Then there is [googles version](http://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=maximized&chdeh=0&chdet=1051300800000&chddm=26653&chls=IntervalBasedLine&q=NASDAQ:MSFT&ntsp=0).

I've seen lots of charts in my search, some links include (for others resources):

- [DynamicDataDisplay](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/07/19/my-new-home-page-enhanced-updated-collection-of-great-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-resources.aspx)
- [Collection of great Silverlight/WPF Data Visualization resources](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/07/19/my-new-home-page-enhanced-updated-collection-of-great-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-resources.aspx)
- [WPF Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf)
- http://timeline.codeplex.com/

Any feedback or links would be fantastic,

thanks guys & girls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [amCharts Stock Chart for WPF and Silverlight](http://wpf.amcharts.com/stock). As far as I understand it does everything you are looking for and it's free (as long as you can live with link back in the corner).

Comment: Thanks Alan, those are a good start, It'd be nice to get some open source tools adding this support.... hummm, might have a look.

If anyone else has any ideas don’t be shy :)